# Send message asynchronously while preserving order

Tags: java, android

So, our QA engineers are working in separate location from us because of the work from home things. Sometimes it is hard for us as developers to debug their finding as we have no direct access to the devices they are holding (and some bugs only reproduceable in their devices), and thus, have no access to the logs (I'm talking about Android application, so the devices are mobile phone).

So we come up with an idea to set up a remote debugging, basically send logs over the internet to our development server, so we can inspect it.

Long story short, we come up with this naive implementation on which we send the log asynchronously with help of Okhttp

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            }
        });
```

Yet, we quickly discovered a problem that sending the log this way doesn't guarantee the log order, which can make debugging confusing.

Is there any clean way we can preserve the order of the log while sending it asynchronously still? (We want the network part to be asynchronous, as we don't want the tester experienced jitters whenever we send a log).

I'm avoiding any complex server side logic with chunk ID or whatever. Hopefully the ordering can be handled in client side. Waiting for the log to be sent before sending another is not an issue, we are not really concerned with logging performance as it will be turned off anyway in production build. As long as the logging doesn't affect the UI, it's fine.

One more requirement, when a crash happened, we want to flush the log and send the stacktrace before the app terminated.

I know I can implement a kind of message queue, and for the later setting the defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, yet every approach that I can think of is kinda messy. I wonder if there is a simple way I can do? Or maybe a framework I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I wonder if there is a simple way I can do?` what does simple mean, isn't that based on opinion ? `Or maybe a framework I can use?` asking for frameworks is off-topic. why aren't you including the times of logs when you send them ? you can then sort by those times to rebuild how stuff occurred ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody. 'what does simple mean, isn't that based on opinion ?' -- Well, first, it depends on your metric, it can be measured in implementation time, I think? But really, I don't know what's wrong with it being an 'opinion', ain't all best practices comes from opinion of what is good, until it is battle tested and become a standard? I'm merely gathering ideas of how people might do it, or maybe someone has an experience with it. 'asking for frameworks is off-topic' -- weird... but alright. But thanks for the idea, I will put that into consideration.

Comment: `I'm merely gathering ideas of how people might do it,` again, not something SO deals with really - if you're going to be asking and voting based on ideas, then it's going to be opinion based, for which questions are closed - "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the responsibility of async around. Right now you hand 'jobs' to the http async processor.

That's not what you actually want, for many reasons. Not JUST because that means your log messages end up out-of-order, but also because this could swamp your http endpoint.

It sounds more sensible that you want something like:

- There is a single thread. Its job is to fetch the next log that needs sending, and send it. It will continually do so until there are no more logs to send, at which point the thread will sleep until one arrives. This thread is synchronous, in that it will only have at most 1 active HTTP connection going.
- Other code in the system just tosses log jobs on the pile, knowing that one log thread will get around to sending them. The task of tossing a log job on the pile must be fast (to avoid the jitter).

That's not too hard to make happen, but before we get there, there is one problem in this design: Imagine your log service is down, or really really slow, and the app is piling up the 'log this' jobs faster than the thread can send them to the HTTP endpoint. What should happen now?

There is no obvious right answer to this admittedly exotic scenario, you must provide an answer. You have 3 broad options:

1. Just start ignoring log messages entirely, and/or take the pile of open logs-to-send: Take the current 1000 queued logs and delete them all, then start the queue over with 'ignored 1000 logs due to congestion' as first log message, and now you have 999 room.
2. Start jittering: Slow the app down - the app's `logThis` call will simply wait until there's room on the pile.
3. Crash the app: The `logThis` call should cause the app to show an error, presumably by throwing an exception and ensuring that this exception bubbles up appropriately.

No matter what your choice ends up being, [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is probably what you're looking for.

### I want to block if the queue is full

That's the simple case, where BlockingQueue is just what you need, out of the box:

```
BlockingQueue<LogJob> logQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(200);

public void log(LogJob job) {
    logQueue.put(job);
}

public void run() {
    // This is the thread's primary loop
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        LogJob job = logQueue.take();
        job.sendToServerUsingSynchronousHttpLibrary();
    }
}
```

### Compress logs

A slight update to your `log` method is needed:

```
public void log(LogJob job) {
    while (true) {
      if (logQueue.offer(job)) return;
      var sink = new ArrayList<LogJob>();
      logQueue.drainTo(sink);
      if (sink.size() == 0) continue;
      if (!logQueue.offer(LogJob.warning("Omitted " + sink.size() + " logs due to congestion"))) throw new IllegalStateException("Feels like you have an infinite loop piling on endless logs somewhere");
    }
}
```

### Crash the app

```
public void log(LogJob job) {
    if (!logQueue.offer(job)) throw new TheExceptionYouWant();
}
```

### Just silently don't send anything if queue full

```
public void log(LogJob job) {
    logQueue.offer(job);
}
```

If you want to spice this up a bit, it may be nice to have the `log` method check if the thread is actually running, and if not, throw something, or start it.

A second concern is what happens at the end: Your app's tester generates a log and then the app hard-crashes. This log is unlikely to make it to your HTTP endpoint. This is the fundamental logging dichotomy, and no simple solution exists to get around it:

- You don't want log statements to have significant timing effects (you do not want the mere presence of log statements to change how an app functions or have them cause significant slowdowns)
- You do not want to 'miss' crucial logs that appear immediately before a significant crash, such as a hard-crash or memory error.

These 2 requirements end up being mutually exclusive unless you start employing some drastic measures that don't quite fully solve the above dichotomy:

- Always wait for confirmation that the log 'made it', be it to disk or to the end point, but this causes the jitter you try to avoid.
- Log to a reasonably fast second process, and then have that process send the logs, which then protects against this process (the one that is creating the logs) hard-crashing: The secondary process will continue to run and send them. But this requires a second, completely independent app, and also requires that the communication between the primary and secondary process is so fast that no significant app slowdown is ever noticable. This is possible but not easy.
- Don't wait and use the queue solution as this answer explains... but that does mean that if the android OS ends up hard killing your app, a whole bunch of logs will be lost. You may want to continue to log locally to the device, so that you can at least ask the tester for their local log if the dev team determines that it feels like a bunch of crucial logs just aren't there.